# I dont understand the while statement in this loop (pointers in C)

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* g(char* s) {
    char* z = s;
    while(*z++ && *z++) s++;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char s[6];
    s[0] = 'a';
    s[1] = 'b';
    s[2] = 'c';
    s[3] = 'd';
    s[4] = 'e';
    s[5] = 'f';
    //s[6] = 'g';    
    printf("%s\n",g(s));
    return 0;
}
```

This code will output a string "def" but I do not know how to explain the while condition above.

Comment: Do you know what `z++` does?  Do you know what `*z++` does?  Do you know what `&&` does?  Have you tried stepping it mentally on some examples?

Comment: You seem to have a bug though, because `g` expects a null-terminated string and `s` is not null-terminated.  Your program will overrun `s` and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that the side-effects of the `(*z++ && *z++)` are uncertain. If the first part is false, the second part won't be checked, or have its side-effect.

Comment: ... and for Nate's reason, the `printf()` behaviour is undefined too.

Comment: *z++ mean we go through each pointer in string z right or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: Tried to run it with a null terminated string like `s[0] = 'a'; s[1] = 'b'; s[2] = 'c'; s[3] = 'd'; s[4] = 'e'; s[5] = '\0';` and the output is cde.

Comment: That's a really confusing way of saying `char s[6] = "abcdef";` Tip: Let the compiler figure out the length for you: `char s[] = "..."` or `char* s = "..."`

Comment: the teacher at my school want me to declare it that way I don't know why but I get what you saying tad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is intended to find the middle of a string.

`char* z = s;` initializes `z` to point to the first character of the string.<sup>1</sup>

The code `while (*z++ && *z++)` looks for two non-null characters:

- `*z` produces the character that `z` is pointing to. The `++` advances `z` to point to the next character. When `*z` is used as a condition in an `&&` operation, it is “true” if the value is not zero and “false” if the value is zero.
- So, if the next character is not zero, the left `*z++` is true, and the `&&` proceeds to evaluate the right operand, another `*z++`.
- If that next character is also not zero, then right `*z++` is true, and the `while` loop evaluates the `s++;` statement. This advances `s` one position.
- Thus, for every two non-zero characters, `s` is advanced by one position, while `z` is advanced twice, once for each `++`.
- When the are not two more non-zero characters remaining, either the left `*z++` or the right `*z++` is “false,” and `s` is not advanced. The loop exits.

Then `s` is returned, having been advanced by half as many characters as there are in the string, rounded down. (So, if there were six characters, it has been advanced three positions. If there were seven, it has also been advanced three positions and is pointing to the middle character.)

As has been noted in comments, the program cannot be relied upon to work because it passes to the function an array of characters that does not include a null terminator. To hold a string of six characters, the array in `main` should be defined as `char s[7];`, and `s[6]` should be set to zero.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The compiler parses `char* z` as `char *z` rather than `char* z`. The C grammar binds `*z` together as a *declarator*, separately from the *type specifier* `char`. Be aware of this in the grammar: Because `char* z, y` is `char *z, y`, it declares `y` to be `char`, not `char*`.